# How to pass a specific logback.xml to a logger?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, logback, slf4j

My project consists of multiple modules. I want one of the modules to use a specific `logback.xml` file for logging which is located in its resources folder. How is it possible to configure this in Java code or with properties?

Now in my Java code I'm getting the logger this way:

`private static final Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);`

Is there a way to somehow pass the specific `logback.xml` to the logger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass it as a run-time parameter.

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml <Your Main Class/ Exe. JAR>
```

Or,

```
System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "/path/to/config.xml");
```